# Create Bars as Sums of Values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This one is sort of hard to define, but I'll try my best. Here's one piece of my 1000 line data:

```
{
    "chartData":[
        {"vNm":"Cyrus Shadfar","vId":5167,"values":[
            {"period":"2014-12-12","id":37419,"amount":99.995},
            {"period":"2014-01-09","id":32630,"amount":180.00},
            {"period":"2014-08-25","id":35100,"amount":371.25},
            {"period":"2014-08-26","id":35102,"amount":393.75},
            {"period":"2014-12-08","id":37545,"amount":49.11},
            {"period":"2014-09-03","id":35848,"amount":90.00},
            {"period":"2014-12-16","id":37673,"amount":69.48},
            {"period":"2014-08-27","id":35909,"amount":371.25},
            {"period":"2014-06-04","id":34727,"amount":80.00},
            {"period":"2014-06-09","id":34810,"amount":90.00},
            {"period":"2014-11-17","id":37191,"amount":130.00},
            {"period":"2014-03-27","id":33642,"amount":90.00},
            {"period":"2014-06-11","id":34300,"amount":90.00},
            {"period":"2014-09-16","id":36115,"amount":99.995},
            {"period":"2014-06-18","id":34958,"amount":90.00},
            {"period":"2014-05-07","id":34428,"amount":90.00},
            {"period":"2014-04-10","id":33855,"amount":90.00},
            {"period":"2014-10-24","id":36830,"amount":100.00},
            {"period":"2014-12-19","id":37424,"amount":100.00},
            {"period":"2014-11-26","id":37446,"amount":90.00},
            {"period":"2014-02-20","id":32678,"amount":180.00},
            {"period":"2014-03-20","id":33360,"amount":90.00},
            {"period":"2014-12-12","id":37550,"amount":69.48},
            {"period":"2014-04-22","id":34010,"amount":90.00},
            {"period":"2014-04-24","id":34068,"amount":90.00},
            {"period":"2014-03-13","id":33500,"amount":90.00},
            {"period":"2014-07-16","id":35287,"amount":52.505},
            {"period":"2014-06-05","id":34726,"amount":90.00},
            {"period":"2014-02-24","id":32933,"amount":90.00},
            {"period":"2014-11-10","id":37183,"amount":192.50},
            {"period":"2014-08-28","id":36015,"amount":202.50},
            {"period":"2014-03-20","id":33643,"amount":90.00},
            {"period":"2014-06-13","id":34951,"amount":90.00},
            {"period":"2014-06-12","id":34381,"amount":80.00},
            {"period":"2014-06-20","id":34959,"amount":90.00}
        ]}
    ]
}
```

There are 25 sets exactly like this with different amounts, periods and id's. All I want is for the bars in my graph to be made of the sum of the amounts, instead of the individual amounts, as I have done here:

```
svg.selectAll(".bars")
    .data(data.chartData, function(d){return d.vNm;})
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "bars")
    .selectAll(".bar")
    .data(function(d){return d.values;})
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.vNm);
    })
    .attr("width", sizeOfSpace)
    .attr("y", function(d){
        return y(d.amount)
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(d.amount); })
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
    .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o5fbqqnq/ (rather large, both codewise and visually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like an easy question, so perhaps I'm misunderstanding it. Why doesn't something like the following work for you?

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data.chartData, function(d){return d.vNm;})
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.vNm);
    })
    .attr("width", sizeOfSpace)
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.values.reduce(function(sum, d) {
            return sum + d.amount;
        }, 0));
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(d.values.reduce(function(sum, d) {
            return sum + d.amount;
        }, 0)); 
     })
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
    .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

You can obviously optimize the code if your data sets are large.

Comment: That works beautifully. I just didn't know where to start. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Just one question. Would I use something similar to that to correctly display the tooltips?